# How do I implement a plus/minus function in django forms

Tags: html, python-3.x, django, django-forms

how do i implement this in django-form?
2/3: 2 is current picked amount of item, 3 is maximum
This form does not work with the model, it will send data after clicking  to the redis server
So, how can i hide form under - n/N +

[image]

Comment: i tried to give answer with Django model form

Comment: I updated the answer which your excet requiement 

I mean - button decrease up to 1 and + button increase up to 3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Here I tried to solve your requirement

#### models.py

```
class Demo(models.Model):
    name =models.CharField(max_length=200)
    total_img = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    photo = models.ImageField(upload_to = 'Images',blank=True,null=True)
```

#### form.py

```
class DemoForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Demo
        fields = "__all__"
```

#### Rendering form in Html

```
{% load static %}
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>
        
    </title>
</head>
<body >
  
    <p>{{form.name.label}}{{form.name}}</p>    
    <p>
         {{form.total_img.label}}
         <a style="background-color: #ffb3b3; padding: 5px; border: 1px solid black; cursor: pointer; " onclick="dec()">-</a>
         {{form.total_img}}
         <a style="background-color: #b3ffb3; padding: 5px; border: 1px solid black; cursor: pointer;" onclick="inc()">+</a>
    </p>
    <p>{{form.photo.label}}{{form.photo}}</p>   

<script>
function inc() {
    let number = document.querySelector('[name="total_img"]');
    if  (number.value > parseInt(2)){
        alert("You can increase up to 3")
    }
    else {
        number.value = parseInt(number.value) + 1;
        console.log(number.value);
    }
}

function dec() {
    let number = document.querySelector('[name="total_img"]');
    if (parseInt(number.value) > 1) {
        number.value = parseInt(number.value) - 1;
    }

    else {
        alert("You can decrease up to 1")
    }
}
    
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

#### Output Becomes like this

[image: ![enter image description here]

### NOTE - Here I wrote javascript for handle + and - buttons.buttons work by targeting the name of the Number Input

Answer (score 1):

Consider having a look at:
`django.forms import widgets, inlineformset_factory`
This would be valuable based on your use case but it depends on how you define your code.

Comment: thanks for taking the time to answer my question.  
unfortunately I didn't find anything in widgets, but I found a simple solution in this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XwM7oBc1i4M